# Markers are displayed incorrectly

Tags: php, url, google-maps-static-api

I am using google static map and I wan to display the markers on map, the url is generated on serverside and **almost** works, but currently there's some strange problem. About 50% of the markers are displayed incorrectly.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x480&zoom=7center=Estonia&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%207%257C000%257Cfff|Harju+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%202%257C000%257Cfff|Hiiu+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%206%257C000%257Cfff|Ida-Viru+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%2012%257C000%257Cfff|J%C3%B5geva+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%205%257C000%257Cfff|J%C3%A4rva+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%204%257C000%257Cfff|L%C3%A4%C3%A4ne+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%208%257C000%257Cfff|L%C3%A4%C3%A4ne-Viru+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%203%257C000%257Cfff|P%C3%B5lva+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%204%257C000%257Cfff|P%C3%A4rnu+maakond&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%202%257C000%257Cfff|Rapla+maakond&sensor=true
```

[Link to map](http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x480&zoom=7center=Estonia&maptype=roadmap&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%207%257C000%257Cfff|Harju+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%202%257C000%257Cfff|Hiiu+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%206%257C000%257Cfff|Ida-Viru+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%2012%257C000%257Cfff|J%C3%B5geva+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%205%257C000%257Cfff|J%C3%A4rva+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%204%257C000%257Cfff|L%C3%A4%C3%A4ne+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%208%257C000%257Cfff|L%C3%A4%C3%A4ne-Viru+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%203%257C000%257Cfff|P%C3%B5lva+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%204%257C000%257Cfff|P%C3%A4rnu+maakond&markers=icon%3ahttp%3A%2F%2Fchart.apis.google.com%2Fchart%3Fchst%3Dd_bubble_icon_text_small%26chld%3Dhome%257Cbb%257C%202%257C000%257Cfff|Rapla+maakond&sensor=true)

Comment: Why are they displayed 'incorrectly', define 'incorrectly'.

Comment: Well if you visit the URL you can see that all the markers should be displayed as custom markers not default red pin.

Comment: just a wild guess, i think the url gets to long...

Comment: Can you try with static images instead of ones generated through google charts?  It'd be good to eliminate that link.

Comment: @Breezer, well the url is about 1652 characters long, the max allowed size is 2048 characters.

Comment: @PhillSparks, how can I use static images, if on the bubble is generated custom text? Currently the project runs in localhost and google would not have access to my server(this is actually not big problem, but the text is)

Comment: @jurka for the sake of testing, do you have any where that you can host a few images?  You could pregenerate them from the charts API and link to the hosted images.